# .load() jquery with JSP and Access Database

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

I have got a situation where I call `.load()` with a jsp which returns a html table and values extracted from database.

Every time there is a change through `insert`, `update` or `delete`, .load() is called.

```
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  
{ 
   var success = "Success";
   var updated = "Updated";
   var deleted = "Deleted";

   if(responseText.substr(0,7) == updated)
   {
      document.getElementById('editForm').reset();
      document.getElementById('editFormDiv').style.display = 'none';
      retrive();
      return;
   }
   if(responseText.substr(0,7) == success)
   {
      document.getElementById('addBeneficiary').reset();
      document.getElementById('otherBank').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('bene_name').focus();
      document.getElementById('editFormDiv').style.display = 'none';
      retrive();
      return;
   }
   if(responseText.substr(0,7) == deleted)
   {
      retrive();
      return;
   }
}

function retrive()
{
   $('#updateEditResults').load('retriveBeneficiaryDetails.jsp?process=u');
   $('#updateDeleteResults').load('retriveBeneficiaryDetails.jsp?process=d');
}
```

Now whenever I call it after delete and update, the updated database (with record deleted / edited) is shown. But after insert sql statement the changes are not reflected.

Comment: show us a bit of code or you won't get a quality answer